# Rails and Devise Gem: Avoiding store session for certain controller and action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

for certain ajax calls I want to skip store session. I use devise gem, when and how I can specify actions to exclude for update session?

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the controller add:

```
after_action -> { request.session_options[:skip] = true }
```

As per the comments [here](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb#L183):

> :skip will not a set a cookie in the response nor update the session state